# How to express j+1 in this case?

Tags: python

I'm writing a piece of code to filter some data, and I've come across a problem. I currently have:

```
def accountforfilter(wavelength, flux, filterwavelength, throughput):

    filteredwavelength=[]
    filteredflux=[]

    for i in wavelength:
        for j in filterwavelength:
            if wavelength==filterwavelength:
                j=filterwavelength.index(wavelength)
                filteredwavelength.append(wavelength)
                filteredflux.append(flux*throughput)
            elif filterwavelength<wavelength<filterwavelength(j+1):
                filteredwavelength.append(wavelength)
                filteredflux.append(flux*f(wavelength))
                #f is a function that interpolates using y=mx+c when wavelength and filterwavelength are not the same
            elif wavelength<filterwavelength:
                i+=1
            elif wavelength>filterwavelength:
                j+=1

    return filteredwavelength, filteredflux
```

The problem I have is with the line:

```
elif filterwavelength<wavelength<filterwavelength(j+1):
```

This line doesn't work, I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

If I change the round brackets to square brackets, i.e.

```
elif filterwavelength<wavelength<filterwavelength[j+1]:
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

I'm not sure how to express what I mean in another way.

Comment: You must index the first mention of `filterwavelength` in your `if` statement as well.

Comment: `for j in filterwavelength`, `j=filterwavelength.index(wavelength)` – you should really use more descriptive variable names to avoid these kind of errors.

Comment: don't reuse the variable. `j+=1` is pointless. also, remember that after `i+=1` `i` will be "reset" later. do a debugging session.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use more descriptive variable names to avoid *numerous errors* that exist in your code.

I assume that in your function parameters, `wavelength` and `filterwavelength` are lists. So let’s make that clear by using *plural* names:

```
def accountforfilter(wavelengths, flux, filterwavelengths, throughput)
```

As soon as you do that, comparison like these don’t make much sense anymore:

```
if wavelengths == filterwavelengths:

elif filterwavelengths < wavelengths < filterwavelengths[j+1]:
```

Especially in the second comparison, you are comparing a list, with a list, with a list item.

Finally, when using `for`, the *loop variable* (your `i` and `j`) is set to individual list *items*, not indexes. So you definitely can’t tread those values as indexes. To reflect that, you should name them appropriately:

```
# one wavelength out of all wavelengths
for wavelength in wavelengths:

    # one filterwavelength out of all filterwavelengths        
    for filterwavelength in filterwavelengths:
```

Also note, that when using `for`, you can’t change the way they are iterating. Every iteration, the next item will be handled; you can’t skip or repeat one item (as you seem to be trying with your `i += 1` and `j += 1`. If you need to do that, you will have to use a classic while loop instead:

```
i, j = 0, 0
while i < len(wavelengths):
    while j < len(filterwavelengths):

        if condition:
            i += 1
        else:
            j += 1
```

---

So, in total, the function might look like this (tried my best to understand what’s going on):

```
def accountforfilter (wavelengths, flux, filterwavelengths, throughput):
    filteredWavelengths = []
    filteredFluxes = []

    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < len(wavelengths):
        wavelength = wavelengths[i]

        while j < len(filterwavelengths):
            filterwavelength = filterwavelengths[j]

            if wavelength == filterwavelength:
                filteredWavelengths.append(wavelength)
                filteredFluxes.append(flux * throughput)
            elif j + 1 < len(filterwavelengths) and filterwavelength < wavelength < filterwavelengths[j + 1]:
                filteredWavelengths.append(wavelength)
                filteredFluxes.append(flux * f(wavelength))

            if wavelength < filteredwavelength:
                i += 1
            else:
                j += 1
                # increase j even when both are equal, otherwise we end up in an infinite loop

    return filteredWavelengths, filteredFluxes
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things: This statement:

```
for i in wavelength:
```

produces a sequence of the *values* in the `wavelength` list, not indexes to them.

If you want the indexes as well, use

```
for i, wv in enumerate(wavelength):
    ...
```

Similarly for the `j` loop. Also, this comparison: `wavelength==filterwavelength` is dangerous if the values are floating point. It's a little hard to advise further without more information about what you're trying to acheive.